# Facebook: Notice of Violation

Tags: facebook, authentication, permissions

I've just received a "Notice of Violation" email from Facebook.

**Your desktop web game hosted primarily off Facebook currently accesses user connections when authenticating and/or requests additional permissions beyond age, email, and publishing permissions. (Facebook Platform Policy I.13a).**

I'm at a loss for trying to work out what user connections I'm supposedly accessing. My scope for logging in simply has "email,user_birthday".

I believe these are both allowed, as per the notice. Any ideas?

**EDIT :**

Just re-read the original email I got sent informing me I had policy issues and it states clearly that both "email" and "user_birthday" are allowed.

**If your Connect app is accessing user connections or asking for additional permissions beyond age, email, and our Publishing Permissions, please remove these requests. Your Connect app may no longer access user connections or request additional permissions other than 'user_birthday', 'email', or our publishing permissions such as 'publish_actions' or 'publish_stream' after December 5th.**

So it's obviously something else they have flagged. But I have no idea what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the Notice of violation you are not authorized to access the friend list:

> Desktop web games off of Facebook.com may only use
>   Facebook Login (Authentication, excluding
>   user connections such as friend list), Social Plugins and publishing
>   (e.g., Feed Dialog, Stream Publish, or Open Graph). When
>   authenticating, these games may not request additional permissions
>   other than age, email, and our Publishing Permissions.

Source: http://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: So age is different to user_birthday? I can't seem to find any "age" permission.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/#permissions

Comment: Have also updated my answer mate. Thanks for your help though, still not sure what the problem could be.

Comment: So in this case it's not linked to the permissions you're requesting. What about the graph API calls you're doing after the login? Are you getting the list of friends by any chance or anything similar?

Comment: Yeah, I do get friends IDs who have also installed the app. Is that not allowed?

Comment: Hard to say, the policy is not extremely clear (to say the least) . However I would interpret `excluding user connections such as friend list` as prohibiting you to get the friends Ids.

Comment: Yup, that looks like it. Just found this article which seems to explain it in layman's terms.

http://allthingsd.com/20121205/facebook-wants-game-makers-to-develop-for-its-platform-or-else/ 

Thanks for your help mate. I guess I'll have to remove all the references to the friends list. If you update you answer with that info, I'll approve it.

Comment: I updated my answer. Facebook wants you to develop a canvas application as game are forced to use Facebook payments to monetize there.